# How can I use Javascript to disable a button after submitting a form in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a web form for which I want to prevent multiple submissions. In production, this is accomplished by the submit button having an `onclick="this.disabled=true"` attribute. This way, if the form is submitted and then the user goes back (presumably to "edit" the data, which our users seemed to want to do from time to time), the submit button remains disabled.

This works fine in Firefox, Safari, and Internet Explorer. In Chrome, however, the disable seems to fire before the form submission, thus preventing it from happening. In order to work around this, I changed the button's `onclick` action to:

```
this.disabled=true; $('myform').submit()
```

This results in the form being submitted, but when I use Chrome's back button to return to the form page, the button is no longer disabled. Values I entered into the form before submitting remain, so my guess is that Chrome must be selectively reloading the DOM.

Is there any way to accomplish what I want with Javascript in Chrome? There are other ways to solve this problem, of course, but disabling the button has a highly attractive simplicity to it.

I've tested in Chrome 12.0.742.100 in Linux, and 12.0.742.112 in MacOS X.

Comment: You can have the button initially disabled and enable it at `onload` with JavaScript code.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - the result being that if javascript is disabled, not available or fails to run correctly for whatever reason, the button will not be enabled.

Comment: @Rob can be fixed by using `<noscript>` tags.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: please make this an answer so we can discuss it. It doesn't work, though--unless I'm missing something. Did you test this in Chrome and find that it worked? I'm using 12.0.742.100, which I should have included in the original question (and will now edit to do so).

Comment: Reason it's a comment is because it was just an idea, didn't had the chance to test it. No point posting answer that we already know is not correct, or at least not solving the problem. This said, in my opinion "Back Button issue" is something we can't really solve you can just put message "Please don't use the back button".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider instead using the form's submit to disable the button.

In any case, you sould be dealing with this at the server, there are other ways to submit a form without using the submit button. Disabling the button will not prevent the user from re-submitting the form.

Comment: This disables the button on submit, but the button is enabled again after pressing the back button. Did you test this suggestion? Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the -1. It was not clear from your question that you wanted the button disabled if the user navigates back to the form. I've modified my answer to deal with that.

Comment: Rob, after lots of trial and error, your updated answer shows what I found: there doesn't seem to be a straight Javascript solution to prevent a re-submit. I'll need to go with a cookie- or data-model-based solution. You're +1ed and accepted now, thanks for editing your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/sCgZ9/

Script:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $("#subbut").hide();
  $("#submitted").show();
});
```

CSS:

```
#submitted { display:none }
```

HTML:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" id="subbut" /><span id="submitted">Form submitted</span>
</form>
```

You can set a cookie if you want to decide to show or not show the button

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript

```
    <form name ="myform" method="POST" action="youractionhere" onSubmit="document.getElementById('submit').disabled=true;">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit">
    </form>
```

Using jQuery

```
$("form").each(function() {
        $(this).find("button:submit").click(function() {
                if($('input[type="submit"]').hasClass("disabled")) 
                return false; 
                $('input[type="submit"]').addClass("disabled");
                return true; 
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use to do this

**html**

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <button type="button" class="submit-form" >Save</button>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```
var button = document.querySelector('.submit-form')
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.setAttribute('disabled',true);
    var form = this.closest('form')
    form.submit();
},false);
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).on("click",".submit-form",function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled',true);
    $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $form.submit();
});
```